# Reading from file /etc/resolv.conf and populating in named.conf.options

Tags: puppet

I'm using puppet to generate my named.conf.options file, in order to do this I'd like it to use the forwarders defined in /etc/resolv.conf. What's the best way of doing this, I've been doing it like this (where named.conf.options.erb contains ) - but this runs constantly.

```
file { '/etc/bind/named.conf.options':
    ensure => present,
    content => template('my_template_location/named.conf.options.erb'),
    replace => true,
}
->
exec { "add_nameserver":
    command => '/bin/sed -i "s/<name_server>/$(grep nameserver/etc/resolv.conf | tr -d [a-z])/g" /etc/bind/named.conf.options',
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An exec will always run unless it has something to limit it. There are a number of parameters you can set.

In your case, it sounds like you want the exec to run only when your file changes. You might want to use the `refreshonly` parameter on your exec.

First, change the require arrow to a notify arrow, from `->` to `~>`. This will cause puppet to refresh the exec whenever the file changes.

Second, add `refreshonly => true` to your exec. This will cause the exec to only run when it is refreshed by some other resource.

You'll end up with the following:

```
file { '/etc/bind/named.conf.options':
    ensure  => present,
    content => template('my_template_location/named.conf.options.erb'),
    replace => true,
}
~>
exec { "add_nameserver":
    command     => '/bin/sed -i "s/<name_server>/$(grep nameserver/etc/resolv.conf | tr -d [a-z])/g" /etc/bind/named.conf.options',
    refreshonly => true,
}
```

You can check out some of the other ways to limit an exec on the [Puppet Type Reference Page](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#exec).

Comment: Cool, this looks perfect - thanks very much for your help, no idea why I've not got round to using refreshonly yet; but reading through the links you've posted suggests this will be ideal.

Answer (score 1):

You can not get desired state this way because you are modifying the same resource (file /etc/bind/named.conf.options) with two different declarations.

Normally you have to avoid exec resources in Puppet because is difficult to keep state and idempotence while executing "old-school" commands.

So, the best way to get your desired behaviour is to create a custom fact [1] that exposes your nameservers to any resource and then include it in your ERB template.

```
Facter.add(:nameservers_array) do
  setcode do
    nameservers = Facter::Core::Execution.exec('grep nameserver/etc/resolv.conf | tr -d [a-z]')
    nameservers_array = nameservers.split(" ")
    nameservers_array
  end
end
```

You have another example here: https://www.jethrocarr.com/2013/11/05/exposing-name-servers-with-puppet-facts/

[1] https://docs.puppetlabs.com/facter/latest/fact_overview.html

Comment: I'm less keen on doing this as I want to avoid having custom facts and keep with the basics. I ended up moving the file, then replacing it and setting the sed exec to refreshonly (as detailed above) this works well, it's a little convoluted perhaps; but it eliminates to the need for custom facts.

Comment: ok, but then you need put `replace => false`, if not your change will be reverted by the file resource.

Comment: Ah, I understand what you're saying, yeah this is how I did it in the end, thanks :D